# Discrete Math and Combinatorics, Proving subset exists under certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I wasn't sure how to title this post so excuse me on that part. The question which I'm trying to solve is the following:

Show that any collection of 8 positive integers whose sum is 20 has a subset summing to 4, Hint: Use PHP

I'm not too sure how to go about doing this question, if someone could get me pointed in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Edit: I should point out, I'm like 99.9% sure that PHP is pigeonhole principle

Comment: The,"collection" of eight positive integers that sum to $20$ must include duplicates,  since otherwise the sum would be too big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  If such a subset does not exist, then $4$ cannot be a summand, there can be at most one $2$, and you cannot have both $1$ and $3$.  What is the smallest sum you can obtain under these conditions?